# My question was misunderstood, should I update or ask a new one?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564732/inject-an-external-property-into-spring-context) on Stackoverflow which was, judged by the answers, misunderstood. However it got some upvotes which makes me think it might be useful in the future nonetheless.

I would want to ask basically the same question again (maybe link to the 'wrong' one) and explain my problem more clearly.

On the other hand i don't like to search SO and find many similar questions. It's makes it harder to find what I'm looking for.

Which would be more polite to our fellow community?

Comment: Please post a link to the question in question.

Comment: Of course. (It was already in my clipboard.)

Answer (score 2):

If the answers are good for the question that was asked, I'd leave that one alone and ask a new one.  Explain in the new question that it's similar but not the same as the old one and give specific details as to how they're different.